# Adding Values to an array while increasing it's size in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to add the total sales inside an array while increasing it's size. Am i doing something incorrect in my code or is everything just wrong?

I am a beginner in java,just starting out to learn about methods and classes, so any advice would help.

```
do {
    counter++;
     System.out.println(trans.length);
     System.out.println(counter);
    System.out.println("How many CD/s would you like to buy?");
    cd = scan.nextInt();
    double cd_sales = sales(cd, CD_PRICE, HST);
    System.out.println("How many DVD/s would you like to buy?");
    dvd = scan.nextInt();
    double dvd_sales = sales(dvd, DVD_PRICE, HST);

    double cart = cd + dvd;
    double total_sales;

    if (cart > 7) {

        total_sales = total(cd_sales, dvd_sales, discount);
        System.out.println(total_sales);
        counter++;
    } else if (cart > 14) {

        total_sales = total(cd_sales, dvd_sales, sup_discount);
        System.out.println(total_sales);    
        counter++;
    } else {

        total_sales = cd_sales + dvd_sales;
         System.out.println(total_sales);
            counter++;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<trans.length;i++){ 
        trans[0]=total_sales;
        System.out.println(trans.length); 
        double[] newtrans = Arrays.copyOf(trans, counter+1);
       newtrans[counter]=trans[0];
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newtrans));
    }
    //double sum=Arrays.stream(trans).sum();
    System.out.println("New Customer? Y/N");
    ans = scan.next().charAt(0);

} while ((ans == 'Y') && (ans != 'N') || (ans == 'y') && (ans != 'n'));
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you have now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase array size and add every new element on the top of the array?](/questions/37097965/how-to-increase-array-size-and-add-every-new-element-on-the-top-of-the-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your code snippet, the for-loop is suspicious to me. Probably, you need to replace it with just this 2 lines:

```
double[] newtrans = Arrays.copyOf(trans, counter+1);
newtrans[counter] = total_sales;
```

However, unless you are forced to use array as your data structure, consider using [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). The whole purpose of `ArrayList` is to be re-sizable array.

Also, if you know expected size and want to minimize resizings, you have an option to create `ArrayList` with initial capacity:

```
List<Double> trans = new ArrayList<>(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help! I managed to get the output that i wanted, by using ArrayList and fixing my for loop. This is the code that did what i wanted

```
  for(int i=0;i<trans.length;i++){
          newtrans.add(i, total_sales);

        }
```